# java: load HTTPS url with client certificate

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate

I installed a pkcs12 certificate and could load the url "httpsURL" on browser.

But my standalone java program is not able to do the same.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "d:/keys2222/prince.p12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
URL url = new URL("httpsURL"); // URL is perfect
URLConnection con = url.openConnection(); // fails here
```

please help me

Comment: Please post exactly the error and stack trace of the error

Comment: Have you imported the key into the keystore?

Comment: @user2013926 You've had 50 minutes to provide the actual error and stack trace as requested. Until you do so this is not a real question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a self-signed certificate the JVM is not trusting it, so `https` URLs don't work.
You need to add it to JVM's keystore with the `keytool` 
see this [article](http://www.webfarmr.eu/2010/04/import-pkcs12-private-keys-into-jks-keystores-using-java-keytool/).

**EDIT:** Sorry, I forgot to mention that you need to specify JVMs default keystore `cacerts`. This [article](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1533825) will show you how it is done.

Also note that your certificate must match your URL **exactly**.

Comment: I exported the certificate from chrome as .cer format.   <br/>
 and did  <br/>
keytool -import -alias prince -keystore "C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.6.0/lib/security/cacerts" -file d:/exported.cer

  <br/>
still fails

<br/>
getting "keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect" message

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting `java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found` is that the `CN` of the certificate does not match the hostname of the URL you're accessing the server by. So you either need to create a certificate with the correct `CN`, or you can write your own `HostNameVerifier` to ignore the problem. But if you do that, make sure you remove that code when you're done testing. [This document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19355-01/820-1072/ahicy/index.html) specifies how you can do that:

```
javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
    new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier(){

        public boolean verify(String hostname, javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
            if (hostname.equals("theHostname")) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
);
```

Comment: I did the above and still getting the exception ..................   `Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

aused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`